# PHP WHILE statement iterating over array length

Tags: php

im learning some oop by watching some carts tutorials and im finding two different behaviors over what i think is the same thing, and i cant understand why:
1- the while stamennt should iterate while the condition its TRUE, but i see code only iterating accordingly to the length of an array provided as argument (which doesn't make sense for me, but it does):
here is the example:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    
                    echo '<pre>'; print_r($row); echo '</pre>';
                    // component($row['product_name'], $row['product_price'], $row['product_image'], $row['id']);
                }
```

in the above case it only iterates 4 times cause that's the length of the array.

but then i tried to replicate this to check it out

```
<?php
$test = ["nro1" =>1 , "nro2" => 2];
while ($test){
print_r($test); 
}
```

and its iterating forever, (that makes sense cause the array its always TRUE, independently from its length )

can someone shed some light on this for me please? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First case is not an array but a `mysqli_result` object. As the function is being called, it moves the internal pointer of the `mysqli_result` until it returns false. Second case you just loop the same variable, which will always evaluate to `true`. You can "emulate" the behavior with something like:

```
<?php
$test = ["nro1" =>1 , "nro2" => 2];

while ($item = current($test)) {
    print_r($item); 
    next($test);
}
```

or better yet:

```
<?php
$test = [1,2,3];

while ($item = current($test)) {
    echo $item;
    next($test);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first snippet is calls `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` each time through the loop. Each time this is called, it returns the next row of results from the query as an array.

When it reaches the end of the results, it returns `FALSE`. That causes the condition to fail, and the loop exits.

Your second snippet loops forever because `$test` never changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
bro , in the first example, if u look better :

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){}

   the mysqli_fetch_assoc is a function that can count the MYSQL results COUNT.

i mean that function developed for the MySQL select query results.
but in the second Example:
   while ($test)

while continue until the condition is TRUE,
when u use condition like this, that's only means , If $test DEFINED, then Exit Loop, else Continue.
you better use FOR EACH instead While.

   For Each($test as $item){
      //do something
    }
```